# Is there any way to disable a function in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have a function associated with a checkbox's event handler. When I check the checkbox the function is being called and it does something. So I wanna know how do I disable that function by unchecking that checkbox? 
and here's the code snippet :

```
$('#mControl').change(function() {
if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    mcs();
} else {
    $(this).unbind("change");
}});
```

Comment: Define "stop", it's not clear what you mean. Also, it would be useful to know *which function* you want to "stop."

Comment: There is nothing to process in your `else` statement, what exactly you are looking for?

Comment: Side note: In the `change` handler, `this.checked` is a much simpler way to write `$("#mControl").is(':checked');`, as `this` will be a reference to the relevant checkbox and `checked` reflects its state.

Comment: I want to stop the 'mcs()' function on unchecking a checkbox.

Comment: It depends on `mcs` implementation. There is not common way to abort function calls.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need call this function only once, on first change, isn't it? You need

```
$(this).off('change');
```

at the end of function.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if it's what you need :

```
$('#mControl').change(function(e) {
if ($('#mControl').is(':checked')) {
    mcs();
} else {
  $(this).unbind("change");
}});
```